# Make transactional query a non-transactional query

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo

I'm using Java, JDO, and App Engine.

My `PersistenceManager` is "created" with the setting of:

`<property name="datanucleus.appengine.autoCreateDatastoreTxns" value="true"/>`

Meaning it will auto-create transactions and i don't have to write: `pm.currentTransaction().begin()` and `.commit()` each time.

But now I have an query I want to be non-transactional. How can I accomplish this?

I found a method called `setNontransactionalWrite(boolean)` but according to the docs it says:

> If true, allow persistent instances to be written without a
>   transaction active.

It doesn't say anything about actually *making* the query non-transactional query, only that it will write even if the query is not transactional.

In other words. I want the current `PersistenceManager` instance to be non-transactional, how can this be accomplished?

Comment: Can't you create a new PersistenceManager?

Comment: Hmm, thank you for your thoughts, I could do that, but then I have to define a new ´persistence-manager-factory´. I was hoping there was some property I could access to change this.

Comment: huh? if you want a query to be nontransactional in a JDO sense then you just don't put tx.begin/tx.commit around it. That's all there is. This AppEngine-specific property is nothing to do with "JDO"

Comment: @NeilStockton But as I understand it, isn't all queries performed as transactions when the 'autoCreateDatastoreTxns' property is set to true?

Comment: Could you elaborate on why setNontransactionalWrite(boolean) doesn't work for what you want?

Doesn't it allow a real time write without a transaction? Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: @LiY Yes that is indeed what I want, but for that to happen the write-operation need to be non-transactional to begin with. In other words I'm looking for a method that would be equivalent to "setOperationToNOTBeATransaction". And now you probably gonna say "but isn't the operation already transaction-less", normally yes. But under my impressions it's not due to the flag that the PM is created with: <property name="datanucleus.appengine.autoCreateDatastoreTxns" value="true"/>